# Create a table in the sharepoint database using C#

Tags: c#, database, sharepoint

How to create A new table in the sharepoint database from c# using the sharepoint libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own database and store data inside there. You can use web.config (See [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx) class) to store your connection string But do not interact with SharePoint database in a direct way, unless you want problems.

Maybe you need [SLAM!](http://slam.codeplex.com/) (SharePoint List Association Manager) or maybe you choose path of creating your own database

Answer (score 4):

It is not recomended to edit the sharepoint database. You can use the sharepoint list as a storage repository or create a new database and use it along with a custom webpart.

What is the need for a new table?